# Farneback optical flow - dealing with pixels out of view, pixels with wrong flow result, different size image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opticalflow, remap

I am writing my thesis and one part of the task is to **interpolate between images to create intermediate images**. The work has to be done in c++ using openCV 2.4.13.
The best solution I've found so far is **computing optical flow and remapping**. But this solution has two problems that I am unable to solve on my own:

- There are pixels that should go **out of view** (bottom of image for example), but they do not.
- Some pixels do not move, creating a **distorted result** (upper right part of the couch)

What has made the flow&remap approach **better**:

- Equalizing the intensity. This i'm allowed to do. You can check the result by comparing the couch form (centre of remapped image and original).
- Reducing size of image. This i'm NOT allowed to do, as I need the same size output. Is there a way to **rescale the optical flow** result to get the bigger remapped image?

Other approaches tried and **failed**:

- cuda::interpolateFrames. Creates incredible ghosting.
- blending images with cv::addWeighted. Even worse ghosting.

Below is the code I am using at the moment. And images: [dropbox link with input and result images](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gnppax0rrs7s0eo/AAA3OS2pGpzgu9r21iuF9nUla?dl=0)

int main(){

```
cv::Mat second, second_gray, cutout, cutout_gray, flow_n;
second = cv::imread( "/home/zuze/Desktop/forstack/second_L.jpg", 1 );
cutout = cv::imread("/home/zuze/Desktop/forstack/cutout_L.png", 1);
cvtColor(second, second_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvtColor(cutout, cutout_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY );

///----------COMPUTE OPTICAL FLOW AND REMAP -----------///
cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback( second_gray, cutout_gray, flow_n, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0 );
cv::Mat remap_n; //looks like it's drunk.
createNewFrame(remap_n, flow_n, 1, second, cutout );
cv::Mat cflow_n;
cflow_n = cutout_gray;
cvtColor(cflow_n, cflow_n, CV_GRAY2BGR);
drawOptFlowMap(flow_n, cflow_n, 10, CV_RGB(0,255,0));

///--------EQUALIZE INTENSITY, COMPUTE OPTICAL FLOW AND REMAP ----///
cv::Mat cutout_eq, second_eq;
cutout_eq= equalizeIntensity(cutout);
second_eq= equalizeIntensity(second);

cv::Mat flow_eq, cutout_eq_gray, second_eq_gray, cflow_eq;
cvtColor( cutout_eq, cutout_eq_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY );
cvtColor( second_eq, second_eq_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY );

cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback( second_eq_gray, cutout_eq_gray, flow_eq, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0 );
cv::Mat remap_eq;
createNewFrame(remap_eq, flow_eq, 1, second, cutout_eq );
cflow_eq = cutout_eq_gray;
cvtColor(cflow_eq, cflow_eq, CV_GRAY2BGR);
drawOptFlowMap(flow_eq, cflow_eq, 10, CV_RGB(0,255,0));

cv::imshow("remap_n", remap_n);
cv::imshow("remap_eq", remap_eq);
cv::imshow("cflow_eq", cflow_eq);
cv::imshow("cflow_n", cflow_n);
cv::imshow("sec_eq", second_eq);
cv::imshow("cutout_eq", cutout_eq);
cv::imshow("cutout", cutout);
cv::imshow("second", second);

cv::waitKey();

return 0;
```

}

Function for remapping, to be used for intermediate image creation:

```
void createNewFrame(cv::Mat & frame, const cv::Mat & flow, float shift, cv::Mat & prev, cv::Mat &next){
    cv::Mat mapX(flow.size(), CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat mapY(flow.size(), CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat newFrame;
    for (int y = 0; y < mapX.rows; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < mapX.cols; x++){
            cv::Point2f f = flow.at<cv::Point2f>(y, x);
            mapX.at<float>(y, x) =  x + f.x*shift;
            mapY.at<float>(y, x) =  y + f.y*shift;
        }
    }
    remap(next, newFrame, mapX, mapY, cv::INTER_LANCZOS4);
    frame = newFrame;
    cv::waitKey();
}
```

Function to display optical flow in vector form:

```
void drawOptFlowMap (const cv::Mat& flow, cv::Mat& cflowmap, int step, const cv::Scalar& color) {
    cv::Point2f sum; //zz
    std::vector<float> all_angles;
    int count=0; //zz
    float angle, sum_angle=0; //zz
    for(int y = 0; y < cflowmap.rows; y += step)
        for(int x = 0; x < cflowmap.cols; x += step)
        {
            const cv::Point2f& fxy = flow.at< cv::Point2f>(y, x);
            if((fxy.x != fxy.x)||(fxy.y != fxy.y)){ //zz, for SimpleFlow
                //std::cout<<"meh"; //do nothing
            }
            else{
                line(cflowmap, cv::Point(x,y), cv::Point(cvRound(x+fxy.x), cvRound(y+fxy.y)),color);
                circle(cflowmap, cv::Point(cvRound(x+fxy.x), cvRound(y+fxy.y)), 1, color, -1);
                sum +=fxy;//zz
                angle = atan2(fxy.y,fxy.x);
                sum_angle +=angle;
                all_angles.push_back(angle*180/M_PI);
                count++; //zz
            }
        }
}
```

Function to equalize intensity of images, for better results:

```
cv::Mat equalizeIntensity(const cv::Mat& inputImage){
    if(inputImage.channels() >= 3){
        cv::Mat ycrcb;
        cvtColor(inputImage,ycrcb,CV_BGR2YCrCb);
        std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
        cv::split(ycrcb,channels);
        cv::equalizeHist(channels[0], channels[0]);
        cv::Mat result;
        cv::merge(channels,ycrcb);
        cvtColor(ycrcb,result,CV_YCrCb2BGR);
        return result;
    }
    return cv::Mat();
}
```

So to recap, **my questions**:

- Is it possible to **resize Farneback optical flow** to apply to 2xbigger image?
- How to deal with **pixels that go out of view** like at the bottom of my images (the brown wooden part should disappear).
- How to deal with **distortion** that is created because optical flow wasn't computed for those pixels, while many pixels around there have motion? (couch upper right, & lion figurine has a ghost hand in the remapped image).

Answer (score 0):

With OpenCV's **Farneback optical flow**, you will only get a *rough estimation* of pixel displacement, hence the distortions that appear on the result images.

I don't think optical flow is the way to go for what you are trying to achieve IMHO. Instead I'd recommend you to have a look at *Image / Pixel Registration* for instace here : http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d61/group__reg.html

*Image / Pixel Registration* is the science of matching pixels of two images. Active research is ongoing about this complex non-trivial subject that is not yet accurately resolved.

Comment: Thanks, but unless I'm very wrong - I cannot use this approach since it does not exist in opencv 2.4.13.

Comment: @ZaneZake My bad. Indeed, the _registration_ module I was talking about is only available in the [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) repo.